# Sinatra Flexible File Inclusion/Update Without Restart

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I'm needing a way to insert a warning line (`Bootstrap` `alert`) to say the site will go under maintenance in 10 minutes.  I'm using `Sinatra 2.0.5` and I want to minimize the work involved for on-the-fly warnings like this that I can modify manually.  I can't leave the application set with a `tmp/always_restart.txt` meaning 'always restart'.  The production files I would like to edit to have this insertion visible.

Is there a way of using `sinatra/reloader` to restart or include a single file (I have a `sitemessage.erb` file that's included in the master `erb` layout file)?  Optimally it would appear on modification of that single file.

http://sinatrarb.com/contrib/reloader

**Edit: Further info:**

I've tested in `:development` with `tmp/Xalways_restart.txt` disabled, so that it must use `sinatra/reloader`.  It's not finding an `erb` template:

```
Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/rich/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sinatra-contrib-2.0.5/lib/sinatra/views/shorts/about.erb
```